# Internal Server Error 500 when running NReco in AWS App Runner

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, nreco

I am using NReco to create a PDF File from an HTML Template. It is working fine, but when we deploy it to AWS App Runner it fails with the following error:

Error: Internal Server Error

Comment: You are getting an exception in the server while processing the request.  Error can be anything.  Do you mean it is work fine when use localhost?  Then normally in this case you are using a resource in the server that you do not have permission to use or it doesn't exist.   Often this happens with a IIS Server if you try to access the file system.  Solution would be to use a Network drive instead of a drive on the IIS.  Other common reason is if you have a backend database and do not have the right credentials to access the database.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.